# Running Wordpress updates while in production?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

We have a production site powered by Wordpress. In my experience, Wordpress updates tend to go pretty smoothly, but every now an then something goes wrong and so we always run the updates locally or on our dev site first to make sure nothing breaks.

My questions is this: Is it a good practice to commit those changes (from the upgrade) locally and then push the changes to production? ...effectively updating the production site? This *seems* to work, but I know that sometimes updates include modifications to the database. So my fear is that the update will modify my local DB, but NOT the production DB and then cause problems when the newer code runs (expecting the DB to have been modified).

1. Is this is valid concern?
2. Will well-written plugins account for this issue somehow?
3. Is there an entirely different and better way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
I think the purpose of this question was initially unclear. I know very well that I can run the update locally, test it, commit, then run the update in production, commit, then merge. That's what we currently do but it sucks and I'm not sure if it's even necessary. The point of this question is to figure that out, or learn a better way. For example, if someone knows something definitive about the nature of WP updates and how they handle DB modifications, it would pretty much answer this question.

Comment: That's pretty WP specific. Maybe wordpress.stackexchange.com? I don't think the updates mess with anything database wise that could break a site unless you've messed with core stuff. I've been afraid of the same thing when dealing with 3.6 and my custom tables... They were unaffected.

Comment: Working with both wordpress and drupal, I have hosed a few sites from  updates. It took less time to roll back a commit and restore the database than to try and figure out the issue. Yes, some modules and some core updates have db changes but not every time. Spending the time updating locally/testing/committing/pushing is a pain but worth it when something goes wrong. The issues that I have seen are from plugins conflicting with one another, especially after one has an update.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to successfully execute the update in a test environment, you should be able to then execute the same update in your production environment. It might be a bit more work, but its going to give you the most information on whether or not an update will work.

If you are in a virtualzied environment, you should be able to copy your production virtual machine to test the upgrade.

Comment: The issue we run into is that once the update is run locally, we'd prefer to push those changes to production rather than running the update a second time in production, and then have to merge those changes. That's what we currently do, but it seems redundant. That's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it takes a few minutes extra, always stick to best practices. Complete updates locally then push to the dev site. On occasion, a plugin will have a database change but not documented properly.

Best Practice:

1. Wait a day after the update then read the issue queue on the plugin  . If other people had problems with the update, you will know ahead of time.
2. Backup the database
3. git status/git commit, making sure the branch is clean/make any needed commit
4. Complete all necessary updates
5. Clear all cache (twice)
6. Check to make sure all is running smoothly locally.
7. *If there was a database change from the update* Make a new database backup.
8. Push changes to the dev site
9. *If there was a database change* Restore database from #7

edit: Please make sure your local database and code  is identical to the dev site before the backup.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a tool like **WP Staging** to create a test site with a few clicks. Than i update all plugins and if everything is fine, i do the same process on my production site. You find WP Staging on wordpress.org

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you save a copy of your work before doing anything. Also, always check what the update is, sometimes it's just a language add-on which you probably don't need.